# Платёжная система для сайта

Tags: php, wordpress, платежи

Посоветуйте платёжную систему, чтобы на сайте можно было рассчитываться кредитной картой и аудитория сайта будет зарубежная (Европа, США). Плагин woocommerce не будет установлен на сайте. Есть ли плагины, или нужно использовать апи платёжной системы? Работал только с liqpay, проблема возникает именно с выбором платёжной системы для зарубежной аудитории, т.к. с этими платёжками не знаком.
Какие самые популярные сегодня, с хорошей документацией?

Comment: https://developer.payeezy.com/ например. Плагина нет, но API несложное.

Comment: @KAGG Design, подскажите, допустим нужно чтобы после выбора товара и кликнув "Купить", покупателя перенаправило на отдельную страницу, свёрстанную под дизайн сайта с полями для ввода реквизитов.  Можно ли с помощью этой платёжной системы сделать так, чтобы оплата происходила без перехода на платёжный шлюз, т.е. чтобы пользователь не покидал сайт? Есть ли в апи такой функционал, чтобы взять данные карты из формы, и отправить их, получить ответ и вывести результат, при этом пользователь визуально чтобы пользователь оставался на сайте, без перехода на платёжный шлюз?

Comment: Да, там платёж осуществляется через curl, одним запросом. И сразу приходит ответ: да/нет.

Comment: @KAGG Design, в смысле, что за ответ да нет?

Comment: Ответ платёжной системы: принят платёж или нет.